# Convert all 'bytes' to 'str' in an object consiting of random nested built-in types

Tags: python, if-statement

Here's my attempt:

```
def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        return data.decode('ascii')
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
    elif isinstance(data, tuple):
        return map(convert, data)
    else:
        return data
```

Can this be better generalized and or improve legibility?

Comment: What is wrong with this one?

Comment: "better design pattern" - oh.. what kind of design pattern is this? :/

Comment: Just wondering, which operation gave you bytes in the first place? I think the origin should be adjusted vs the result itself ... a lot of components have flags that gives you the results as you need them ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't know about optimisation for speed but I'm *not* a big fan of the `if/return/else` paradigm since it clogs up the code with unnecessary stuff and causes indentation staircases for languages without `elif` (not such a problem here).

Optimising for *readability* (which is usually my first preference), I'd turn all those `elif` lines into `if` and ditch the `else` entirely, reformatting to make it more compact:

```
def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes):  return data.decode('ascii')
    if isinstance(data, dict):   return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
    if isinstance(data, tuple):  return map(convert, data)
    return data
```

Comment: Such a simple change for such a huge improvement in readability

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way would be to use dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
new_data = { key.decode(): val.decode() for key, val in data.items() }
```

**Example:**

```
>>> data = {
...   b'cart1': b'apples',
...   b'cart2': b'oranges',
...   b'cart3': b'grapes'
... }
>>> 
>>> new_data = { key.decode(): val.decode() for key, val in data.items() }
>>> 
>>> new_data
{'cart1': 'apples', 'cart2': 'oranges', 'cart3': 'grapes'}
>>>
```

To convert keys value pairs of type bytes in random order, use:

```
new_data = {
    key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key:
    val.decode() if isinstance(val, bytes) else val
    for key, val in data.items()
}
```

**Example:**

```
>>> data = {
...   b'cart1': 'apples',
...   'cart2': b'oranges',
...   b'cart3': b'grapes'
... }
>>> 
>>> new_data = {
...     key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key:
...     val.decode() if isinstance(val, bytes) else val
...     for key, val in data.items()
... }
>>> new_data
{'cart1': 'apples', 'cart2': 'oranges', 'cart3': 'grapes'}
>>>
```

**Note:** The above code will be better for simple data dictionary. But for complex dictionaries, I would prefer to use [Guy Gangemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4368167/guy-gangemi)'s code which is a modification of [paxdiablo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) answer:

```
def convert(data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes):  return data.decode()
    if isinstance(data, dict):   return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
    if isinstance(data, tuple):  return tuple(map(convert, data))
    if isinstance(data, list):   return list(map(convert, data))
    return data
```

Example:

```
>>> 
>>> def convert(data):
...     if isinstance(data, bytes):  return data.decode()
...     if isinstance(data, dict):   return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
...     if isinstance(data, tuple):  return tuple(map(convert, data))
...     if isinstance(data, list):   return list(map(convert, data))
...     return data
...
>>>
>>> data = {
...     b'fruits': {
...             b'cart1': b'apples',
...             b'cart2': 'oranges',
...             b'cart3': b'grapes',
...             b'cart4': (b'banana', 'pear'),
...             b'cart5': [b'kiwi', b'papaya']
...     },
...     'vegetables': {
...             'cart1': b'carrots',
...             b'cart2': None,
...             b'cart3': {},
...             b'cart4': False
...     }
... }
>>>
>>> convert(data)
{'fruits': {'cart1': 'apples', 'cart2': 'oranges', 'cart3': 'grapes', 'cart4': ('banana', 'pear'), 'cart5': ['kiwi', 'papaya']}, 'vegetables': {'cart1': 'carrots', 'cart2': None, 'cart3': {}, 'cart4': False}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

Extending paxdiablo's answer to handle more use cases resulted in the following:

```
def convert(data):
  if isinstance(data, bytes):      return data.decode()
  if isinstance(data, (str, int)): return str(data)
  if isinstance(data, dict):       return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
  if isinstance(data, tuple):      return tuple(map(convert, data))
  if isinstance(data, list):       return list(map(convert, data))
  if isinstance(data, set):        return set(map(convert, data))
```

It becomes clear that the application of the map function is fairly consistent and we can generalise it.

```
def convert(data):
  data_type = type(data)

  if data_type == bytes: return data.decode()
  if data_type in (str, int): return str(data)

  if data_type == dict: data = data.items()
  return data_type(map(convert, data))
```

Comment: Why convert str & int to str? Seems unnecessary, and often undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

'map' has fallen out of favour to comprehensions. Structural Pattern Matching can be used.

```
def convert(data):
    match data:
        case bytes(): return data.decode()
        case int(): return str(data)
        case str(): return data
        case dict(): return d{convert(k): convert(v) for k, v in data.items()}
        case _: return type(data)(convert(i) for i in data)
```